# forms seem to loose value upon clicking submit. im using xampp as a web server

Tags: php, html

I'm new to php and i just cant figure this out. when i click submit it returns me these errors:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant ‘tireqty’ - assumed '‘tireqty’' in C:\xampp\htdocs\amit\process.php on line 6
Notice: Undefined index: ‘tireqty’ in C:\xampp\htdocs\amit\process.php on line 6
Notice: Use of undefined constant ‘oilqty’ - assumed '‘oilqty’' in C:\xampp\htdocs\amit\process.php on line 7
Notice: Undefined index: ‘oilqty’ in C:\xampp\htdocs\amit\process.php on line 7
Notice: Use of undefined constant ‘plugqty’ - assumed '‘plugqty’' in C:\xampp\htdocs\amit\process.php on line 8
Notice: Undefined index: ‘plugqty’ in C:\xampp\htdocs\amit\process.php on line 8
```

here are my codes.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action=process.php method=”post”>
<label for="tire">Tire</label>
<input type="text" name="tireqty" id="tire"/><br/>
<label for="oil">Oil</label>
<input type="text" name="oilqty" id="oil"/><br/>
<label for="plug">Plugs</label>
<input type="text" name="plugqty" id="plug"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$tireqty = $_POST[‘tireqty’];
$oilqty = $_POST[‘oilqty’];
$plugqty = $_POST[‘plugqty’];
?>
```

Comment: Change `$_POST[‘tireqty’]` to `$_POST['tireqty']` and so forth.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. i did change the smart quotes with reg quotes a while ago but now it's returning me this error: Notice: Undefined index: tireqty in C:\xampp\htdocs\script\process.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: tireqty in C:\xampp\htdocs\script\process.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: plugqty in C:\xampp\htdocs\script\process.php on line 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using smart quotes instead of regular quotes in your _POST array, that's probably causing the problem.  As an aside, it's good practice to always quote your HTML5 attribute values, so it should say - action="process.php"

Comment: thanks for your response! so i used the reqular quotes '   ' for the post array, now it's returning me this error:   Undefined index: tireqty in C:\xampp\htdocs\script\process.php on line 5

Comment: Are you testing if the index was set with the isset function?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 0):

Let me first try and explain what is happening and then tell you how to fix it.

If you see the first error you are getting, it says:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant ‘tireqty’ - assumed '‘tireqty’' in C:\xampp\htdocs\amit\process.php on line 6
```

This itself tells you that PHP is trying to check for an index `‘tireqty’` which doesn't exist. What actually exists is `tireqty`. The same thing is happening in all three statements. The reason behind what is happening is the fact that `‘’` are not the same as `''` or `""`. PHP considers them as a string and if it were to exist then you should have defined something like `define ‘tireqty’ = 'some value'`.

So, your new code will be

```
$tireqty = $_POST["tireqty"];
$oilqty = $_POST["oilqty"];
$plugqty = $_POST["plugqty"];
```

Comment: hi Aniket, thanks for your response I really appreciate it. i did change it a while ago with the regular quotes but now it's returning me this error. Notice: Undefined index: tireqty in C:\xampp\htdocs\script\process.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: oilqty in C:\xampp\htdocs\script\process.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: plugqty in C:\xampp\htdocs\script\process.php on line 9

Comment: @user3021300 From the errors I can make out only one thing that the values in the form are not being passed to `process.php`.